# Which way to return list of quantities to client?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net, ajax

I want to return a list of available quantities of a product (which customer can purchase) to client (for example, 1,2,3...,200). We're considering three methods:

- Return full list of quantities to client, client just need to bind it. This is the current implement, which is easy to implement but it's the waste of bandwidth.
- Return separated min quantity and max quantity, the client have to build a list and then bind them. This is my idea, because we can avoid parsing.
- Return a string in form of 1-200, the client then have to parse to numbers, build list, and then bind them. This is idea of my collage, he said he read it somewhere (thought he can't remember where), it's the popular way of returning quantities list.

Our current requirements do not support segmented quantities (for example, we do not support 1-20, 40-50, 100-200 quantities, we just support 1-200)

Which should be the way to solve this? We're using ASP.NET and AJAX over jQuery.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you give more info: Quantities of what?  Can there be 1,1,200,1,1,0,0,0 ? Or is it 1,2,3,4 (stop)?

Comment: I updated the question, it can only be 1,2,3,4,5....,maxquantity

Comment: Is bandwidth a big concern here? I mean you're looking at maybe 700 bytes of data for the list 1,2,3,...,200

Comment: 700 bytes/products, and we have thousands of products :). If a lot of people go to our website, it would be a nightmare

Comment: are you familiar with json? you can send/receive data in json format.

Comment: Your second option seems the best from what you are saying - you can also make both optional.  If both missing, then use 1..200, if either present then use them. e.g. 4: = 4..200 then :150 - 1..150 and 4:40 = 4..40.  Parsing in javascript (json) should be pretty quick...but as @Steven Schroeder says...is bandwidth a big concern as this is not much data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1: Returning a list of all integers in a range seems hugely wasteful to me. Who knows what quantities will be required in the future? If you ever have products that can be ordered in tens of thousands this could cause big problems.

Option 3: A parseable format is useful when the input needs to be human readable or editable. A good example is the print dialog in MS Word; the user can choose to print pages "1,2,7,9,11" or "5-15", etc. But parsing introduces a whole new possibility for bugs. Even in the simple example "1-200" there is the possibility that the "-" could be interpreted as a minus sign giving "-200" or something similar. If the interface is machine-to-machine, I'd always prefer a clearly semantised interface. With clearly defined interfaces (e.g. parameters "rangeFrom" and "rangeTo") the ambiguity of the interpretation is removed and the only problem to be solved is the implementation. I don't know what your client is, but in any language producing a list of integers from 1 to 200 should be pretty trivial.

I'd definitely go for Option 2: It's a clearly defined interface. It's easy to build and it's efficient over the wire.

Depending on how future-proof you want to be, you could consider choosing Option 2 and faking a kind of overloading. So today you would keep it simple and just return the following:

```
{ 
  "listType": "range",
  "rangeFrom": 1,
  "rangeTo": 200
}
```

The client should check the "listType" return value and for the moment, it would always expect it to be "range". But in the future you could add additional types. For axample

```
{
  "listType": "increment",
  "rangeFrom": 2,
  "rangeto": 20,
  "inc": 2
}

// Interpreted by client as:
//   2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20


{
  "listType": "valuelist",
  "values": [1, 2, 5, 20] 
}

// Interpreted by client as:
//   1, 2, 5, 20
```

This would be simple and efficient today but leave you open to extend easily if new requirements come in later without breaking compatibility.